# PHP: Creating a DOMDocument works fine on MAMP Testing Enviroment, fails on external Server

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

i want to load the content of different html-files (all on the same server/in the same directory) for further processing. For this i want to use the loadHTMLfile method, but it seems i'm not able to create a DOMDocument object on the external Server.

Testcode:

```
<?php
if(!class_exists('DOMDocument')){
echo 'No DOM! ';
}
if(class_exists('DOMDocument')){
echo "DOM! ";
}
echo "test1 ";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
echo "test2 ";
?>
```

Output on local MAMP:

```
DOM! test1 test2
```

Output with script on external server:

```
DOM! test1
```

libxml seems to be installed on the external server (checked via phpinfo), server runs php 5.2.12, MAMP has php 5.2.13.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong or where else i could look for solutions?

tia!

reiber

p.s. i'm a total php-newbie, so don't be hard on me :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP error log (it'll be either logging into the web server's error log, or a seperate file), and/or enable [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) in your .ini file or via ini_set. You can get the log's location with `phpinfo()` (web-based) or `php -i` (command line).

There should be more details in the log or via the displayed errors as to what's causing the script to die.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! i'll check the logfiles and post what i've accomplished...